# How to get and set single values in Pandas MultiIndex Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, setter

I defined a **MultiIndex** Dataframe as follows:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [assets, ['A', 'B', 'C']], 
    names=['asset', 'var']
)
res = pd.DataFrame(0, index=data.index, columns=columns)
```

However, I did not have success setting or updating **single** values of this `Dataframe`. Any suggestion? Or should I move to use `numpy` arrays - because of efficiency?

Comment: Well, how did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with tuples for select MultiIndex columns and set new value like:

```
assets = ['X','Y']
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [assets, ['A', 'B', 'C']], 
    names=['asset', 'var']
)
res = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(3), columns=columns)
print (res)
asset  X        Y      
var    A  B  C  A  B  C
0      0  0  0  0  0  0
1      0  0  0  0  0  0
2      0  0  0  0  0  0

res.loc[0, ('X','B')] = 100
print (res)
asset  X          Y      
var    A    B  C  A  B  C
0      0  100  0  0  0  0
1      0    0  0  0  0  0
2      0    0  0  0  0  0
```